# How should i match the Elmish toNavigable argument types

Tags: f#, url-routing, elmish

I'm trying to learn the SAFE Stack at the moment, specifically attempting to handle URL navigation via Elmish; I've followed the example code on the Elmish site that defines a route mapping function and then passes that to the **parsePath** function. 
However, **Program.toNavigable** expects a **Parser<'a>** type (a type alias for **Location -> 'a**) as its first argument, but the sample code **(parsePath routes)** first argument is a **Location -> 'a option**. 
Obviously i can use function composition to get the correct typing, but it seems like I'm missing something here. Can anyone familiar with URL navigation in Elmish advise?

Comment: Welcome on board. You  might want to add some piece of code in order to attract more replies :)  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a `Parser<'a option>` *is* a `Parser<'a>` (just with another `'a`), so things should compose just fine.

Say, e.g., that the following type defines all navigation:

```
type Route = Blog of int | Search of string
```

Then the parties involved should have the following types:

```
init: Route option -> Model * Cmd<Msg>
parser: Parser<Route option>
urlUpdate: Route option -> Model -> Model * Cmd<Msg>
```

and you compose your program thusly:

```
Program.mkProgram init update view
|> Program.toNavigable parser urlUpdate
|> Program.withReactBatched "elmish-app"
|> Program.run
```

Comment: "Well, a Parser<'a option> is a Parser<'a>" . This is very obviously true - and now i feel a bit stupid . This seems to be what's giving me an error though, so i think I'll need to investigate a bit more.  Thanks for highlighting my blunder.

Comment: Please don't feel stupid, I've stumbled over the types too because I didn't realize that init had to change signature (I had it unit -> Model * Cmd<Msg> at first).

Comment: Thanks @nilekirk. The type matching from the subsequent Program.mkProgram call was the problem, Giving my init function the correct type resolved my issue.
Didn't abide by _the type system is your friend_ mantra.